# Converted Pine Script v2 to v5 but different outcome

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

So I was converting an old pine script v2 via on tradingview to v5 which all worked fine but when I came to use it, it gave me a different result to the v2 script once converted.

[image: V2]

[image: V5]

From what I can see the V2 gets the correct data and uses the high and low of the 'day' correctly while v5 some reason uses the past day data instead of the current data. Unsure how to fix this and have spent a few hours comparing scripts but couldn't figure it out.

Much appreciated if anyone has any idea.

v2 Script -

```
h = security(tickerid, "D", high)
l= security(tickerid, "D", low)

fibext = input(1)
fib6 = l
fib5 = input(0.2360)
fib4 = input(0.382)
fib3 = input(0.50)
fib2 = input(0.618)
fib1 = input(0.786)
fib0 = h
range = (h-l)

fib0plot = h-(range*fibext)
fib1plot = (range*fib1)+l
fib2plot = (range*fib2)+l
fib3plot = (range*fib3)+l
fib4plot = (range*fib4)+l
fib5plot = (range*fib5)+l
fib6plot = (range*fibext)+l

plot(fib0plot, color=gray,linewidth=3, style=solid, title="Fib0")
plot(fib1plot, color=aqua,linewidth=2, style=solid, title="Fib1")
plot(fib2plot, color=gray,linewidth=2, style=solid, title="Fib2")
plot(fib3plot, color=orange,linewidth=2, style=solid, title="Fib3")
plot(fib4plot, color=orange,linewidth=2, style=solid, title="Fib4")
plot(fib5plot, color=aqua,linewidth=2, style=solid, title="Fib5")
plot(fib6plot, color=gray,linewidth=3, style=solid, title="Fib6")
```

V5 Script

```
h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, barmerge.gaps_off)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low, barmerge.gaps_off)

fibext = input(1)
fib6 = l
fib5 = input(0.2360)
fib4 = input(0.382)
fib3 = input(0.50)
fib2 = input(0.618)
fib1 = input(0.786)
fib0 = h
range_1 = h - l

fib0plot = h - range_1 * fibext
fib1plot = range_1 * fib1 + l
fib2plot = range_1 * fib2 + l
fib3plot = range_1 * fib3 + l
fib4plot = range_1 * fib4 + l
fib5plot = range_1 * fib5 + l
fib6plot = range_1 * fibext + l

plot(fib0plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=3, style=plot.style_line, title='Fib0')
plot(fib1plot, color=color.new(color.aqua, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, title='Fib1')
plot(fib2plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, title='Fib2')
plot(fib3plot, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, title='Fib3')
plot(fib4plot, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, title='Fib4')
plot(fib5plot, color=color.new(color.aqua, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line, title='Fib5')
plot(fib6plot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), linewidth=3, style=plot.style_line, title='Fib6')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Default behaviour of security function has changed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed) starting from v3. You need to add `barmerge_lookahead_on` to your `security()` call if you want to have the same outcome.

```
h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Comment: thanks vitruvirus.

I am now trying to add an option to enable different timeframe instead of just 'D' = Daily, such as W for Weeky and M for Monthly, I know I can just change D to whatever them values but I would like it all in one script if possible, what is the best way to do that for the code above as it's a lot different to other scripts i've seen.

I am also trying to add an reverse option for the numbers but does not seem to be working. I've tried reading through tradingview pine script guide but couldn't find it, any chance you can help me on that it be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: okay, i've done the 'D, W, M' option on my script and works fine!

DAILY = "D"
WEEKLY = "W"
MONTHLY = "M"

pivot_time_frame = input.string(title="Timeframe", defval="D", options=["D", "W", "M"])

h = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, pivot_time_frame, high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
l = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, pivot_time_frame, low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

I just need to find how to reverse option so the values are reversed for the lines if you can help!

Is there a way to add labels as well to show the number?

Comment: Please ask a new question for that.